# appengine dev_appserver.py did not use the correct GOPATH

Tags: google-app-engine, go

Per this [go blog](https://blog.golang.org/the-app-engine-sdk-and-workspaces-gopath), the appengine SDK is supposed to be able to detect `GOPATH`, but looks like that is not the case. Instead it is considering some path in the appengine SDK installation dir as the `GOPATH`. Any thoughts on how to make the appengine work with the existing GOPATH, without having to change it?

```
dev_appserver.py app.yaml


................

Can't find package "github.com/gorilla/context" in $GOPATH: cannot find package "github.com/gorilla/context" in any of:
/Users/muly_ae/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/goroot-1.6/src/github.com/gorilla/context (from $GOROOT)
/Users/muly_ae/Applications/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/gopath/src/github.com/gorilla/context (from $GOPATH)
```

Here is my Go env:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/muly_ae/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8.3/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```